# Making input inside div always scale in one line

Tags: html, css, input

I would like to scale my input fields better.

When browser is maximized they look like this:

[image]

On smaller screens they look like this, the input fields goes to the bottom while it should be on the right:

[image]

My code:

```css
.table-body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 952px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-left: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-right: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
}
.table-body div {
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.table-field1 {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 11px;
  padding-right: 11px;
}
.table-field2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #8f268d;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.table-field3 {
  color: #323232;
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.table-field3 input {
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 844px;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  behavior: url(/panel/css/pie/pie.php);
}
```

```html
<div class="table-body">
  <div class="table-header">
    <div class="left">&nbsp;
      <input type="checkbox" name="usun_wszystkie" id="checkbox_all" class="css-checkbox" onchange="checkAll('checkbox[')">
      <label for="checkbox_all" class="css-label">&nbsp;Zaznacz wszystkie</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabela_0">
    <div class="table-field1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="usun[438]" id="checkbox[438]" class="css-checkbox">
      <label for="checkbox[438]" class="css-label"></label>
      <input type="hidden" name="tag[438]" value="test.com">
    </div>
    <div class="table-field2">
      <div>USUŃ</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-field3">
      <input type="text" name="entry" value="test.com">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="table-end"></div>
```

Comment: Keep the left side text fixed width. Use the method given in the dupe.

Comment: @PraveenKumar not duplicate OP never talk about a fixed width on first items ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) to support your project, then try this:

```css
.table-body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 952px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-left: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-right: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
}
.tabela_0 {
  display:flex;
}
.table-body div {
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.table-field1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 11px;
  padding-right: 11px;
}
.table-field2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #8f268d;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.table-field3 {
  color: #323232;
  padding-left: 10px;
  flex-grow:1;
}
.table-field3 input {
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 844px;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  behavior: url(/panel/css/pie/pie.php);
}
```

```html
<div class="table-body">
  <div class="table-header">
    <div class="left">&nbsp;
      <input type="checkbox" name="usun_wszystkie" id="checkbox_all" class="css-checkbox" onchange="checkAll('checkbox[')">
      <label for="checkbox_all" class="css-label">&nbsp;Zaznacz wszystkie</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabela_0">
    <div class="table-field1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="usun[438]" id="checkbox[438]" class="css-checkbox">
      <label for="checkbox[438]" class="css-label"></label>
      <input type="hidden" name="tag[438]" value="test.com">
    </div>
    <div class="table-field2">
      <div>USUŃ</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-field3">
      <input type="text" name="entry" value="test.com">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="table-end"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks :) It worked. I've also added margin-right:11px; to table-field3 and now it's perfectly fine.

Comment: Nice @MarekZakrzewski glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Get the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z1o0fp1n/

I used tables:

```
     <table><tr><td>
            <div class="table-field2">
                <div>USUŃ</div>
            </div>
         </td><td>
            <div class="table-field3">
                <input type="text" name="entry" value="test.com">
            </div>
         </td></tr>
     </table>
```

Also you may use float:

```
 <div class="table-field3" style='float:left;display:block'>
            <input type="text" name="entry" value="test.com">
 </div>
```

Comment: I need to get rid of tables. That's why I've switched to divs.

Comment: Then use display:table

Comment: Or you may use float

Answer (score 0):

flexbox?

```css
.table-body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 952px;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-right: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
}

.table-body div {
  padding: 3px;
}

.table-field2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #8f268d;
}

.table-field3 input {
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  behavior: url(/panel/css/pie/pie.php);
  width: 95%;
}

.tabela_0 {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 3px;
}

.table-field3 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-body">
<div class="table-header">
    <div class="left">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="usun_wszystkie" id="checkbox_all" class="css-checkbox" onchange="checkAll('checkbox[')"><label for="checkbox_all" class="css-label">&nbsp;Zaznacz wszystkie</label></div>
</div>
    <div class="tabela_0"><div class="table-field1"><input type="checkbox" name="usun[438]" id="checkbox[438]" class="css-checkbox"><label for="checkbox[438]" class="css-label"></label><input type="hidden" name="tag[438]" value="test.com"></div><div class="table-field2"><div>USUŃ</div></div><div class="table-field3"><input type="text" name="entry" value="test.com"></div></div>
</div>
```